# How to insert a comment using YouTube Data API for Java without browser login OAuth 2.0?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-java-client

I can add comments using the YouTube Data API, using the code below coming from the YouTube Data API's [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert).

But every time a browser is opened and I have to login and choose my google account. How can I change that so the login is saved and to execute the program without interruptions?

```
/**
 * Sample Java code for youtube.commentThreads.insert
 * See instructions for running these code samples locally:
 * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#java
 */

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Comment;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentSnippet;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThread;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThreadSnippet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ApiExample {
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRETS= "client_secret.json";
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "API code samples";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Create an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = ApiExample.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .build();
        Credential credential =
                new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized API client service
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
     */
    public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Call function to create an API service object. Define and
     * execute API request. Print API response.
     *
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException {
        YouTube youtubeService = getService();

        // Define the CommentThread object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
        CommentThread commentThread = new CommentThread();

        // Add the snippet object property to the CommentThread object.
        CommentThreadSnippet snippet = new CommentThreadSnippet();
        Comment topLevelComment = new Comment();
        CommentSnippet commentSnippet = new CommentSnippet();
        commentSnippet.setTextOriginal("This is the start of a comment thread.");
        topLevelComment.setSnippet(commentSnippet);
        snippet.setTopLevelComment(topLevelComment);
        snippet.setVideoId("gQquhwSy-_w");
        commentThread.setSnippet(snippet);

        // Define and execute the API request
        YouTube.CommentThreads.Insert request = youtubeService.commentThreads()
                .insert("snippet", commentThread);
        CommentThread response = request.execute();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google provides [a set of sample programs](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples) that exemplify the usage of its [Client Library for Java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services) (also for a couple of other implementation programming languages/environments).

There you can find the source file [`Auth.java`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java) that implements persistence of user credential data:

```java
/**
 * Shared class used by every sample. Contains methods for authorizing a user and caching credentials.
 */
public class Auth {

    /**
     * Define a global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    /**
     * Define a global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    /**
     * This is the directory that will be used under the user's home directory where OAuth tokens will be stored.
     */
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";

    /**
     * Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data.
     *
     * @param scopes              list of scopes needed to run youtube upload.
     * @param credentialDatastore name of the credential datastore to cache OAuth tokens
     */
    public static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException {

        // Load client secrets.
        Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);

        // Checks that the defaults have been replaced (Default = "Enter X here").
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
                || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential "
                            + "into src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // This creates the credentials datastore at ~/.oauth-credentials/${credentialDatastore}
        FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));
        DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
                .build();

        // Build the local server and bind it to port 8080
        LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();

        // Authorize.
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
    }
}
```

You may find many relevant use cases of the class `Auth`, for example, in the `data` subfolder, the program [`CommentThreads.java`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/CommentThreads.java).